# How do I set the front page programmatically?

Tags: frontpage

I need to allow my users to set the default page of the blog. So when someone visits, "www.example.com/blog/" the page they see is either the blog posts list or a specific page.

It looks like I can tell which page is already set using:

```
get_option( 'page_on_front' ): returns the ID of the static page assigned to the front page.
```

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Can I change that by using:

```
set_option( 'page_on_front', 10 );
```

How would I remove a specific front page that has already been set? 
Do I set it to null?

**UPDATE:**

I found this call to check if showing blog posts:

```
get_option( 'show_on_front' ) == 'posts';
```

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

BTW This is on a network site (Wordpress MU).

Comment: Logically, you could do it but it is not a good approach, just define a constant of that page id. And it reduce query loading time!

Comment: You want registered users to set the default page when they visit the site and are logged in?

Comment: Sort of. I want to do it through a UI I have

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - if you want this to be per-user, then the solution I gave is not correct and you're going about this wrong. that's a global setting for all visitors.

Comment: When a user logs into their site they can go to their reading page and set the default home page for their site. I want my application to be able do that as well. I'm doing this on a network site (Wordpress MU).

Comment: So I would use update_user_option() or update_blog_option() to set this value on a per user basis? I'm using multisite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually enter the admin URL `wp-admin/options.php` you'll see a list of all options and their values.

`show_on_front` is `page` when a page is selected to show on front. `page_on_front` and `page_for_posts` are `0` when no pages are chosen.

You can use [`update_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) to change these values, there is no `set_option` function.

Comment: Can I use one of these properties to hold a value? If I set page_for_posts to a value will that change anything or do I need to set show_on_front to "page" as well? I want to set the pageforposts to a value I can reference later.

Comment: If you're doing something non-standard, just save the value in your own option.

Comment: The answer is to store a custom option per blog with `update_blog_option(blog_id, "project_site_option", value);` FYI API parameters may not be in correct order.

Comment: you're using multisite? your question says nothing about multisite.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I mentioned it in the comments but not the original post. I'll update it. BTW I was agreeing with your comment, "If you're doing something nonstandard save your own option".